# How to create a service for the class with constructor arguments from a vendor package class?

Tags: dependency-injection

I am trying to inject class from [FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php)
in my custom service of a module.

But the class has two constructor arguments.
So how can I pass those arguments in my custom service.

##### my_module.services.yml

```
services:
  # FFMPEG Factory
  my_module.php_ffmpeg:
    class: FFMpeg\FFMpeg
    autowire: true
```

I understand that as there are two parameters in the costructor,
we need to pass two arguments in service definition
but the class doesn't have factory method.
So, what arguments should I pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory services are nothing more than classes that instantiate and return objects as an injectable (e.g. [`LoggerChannelFactory`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Logger%21LoggerChannelFactory.php/class/LoggerChannelFactory/9) creates [`LoggerChannel`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Logger%21LoggerChannel.php/class/LoggerChannel/9) instances as logger services). You can create a factory that instantiates `FFMpeg\FFMpeg`, makes it a service, and inject it to whatever needs it. This still fulfills dependency-injection duties. Your code won't be using FFMpeg directly but via the factory, and you can mock away the factory during testing.

```
// my_module/src/FFMpegFactory.php
class FFMpegFactory {
  public static function get() {
    $ffmpeg = /* instantiate driver */
    $ffprobe = /* instantiate probe */
    return new FFMpeg($ffmpeg, $ffprobe);
  }
}

// my_module/src/OtherService.php
class OtherService {
  public function __construct(FFMpeg $php_ffmpeg) {
    $this->ffmpeg = $php_ffmpeg;
  }
}

// my_module/my_module.services.yml
services:
  my_module.php_ffmpeg:
    class: 'FFMpeg\FFMpeg'
    factory: ['\Drupal\my_module\FFMpegFactory', 'get']
  my_module.other_service:
    class: '\Drupal\my_module\OtherService'
    arguments:
      - '@my_module.php_ffmpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor arguments for the class are `FFMpegDriver $ffmpeg` and  `FFProbe $ffprobe`. Those are the ones to inject. You must create those object instances as services also.

Alternatively you can create a custom factory to build the object.